# react-native run-ios builds sporadically

Tags: ios, react-native

```
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.58.4
```

When I use react-native cli invoking build ios to simulator, it is not building any app. It just opens IOS simulator.

This is everything what i get:

```
Found Xcode project HelloWorld.xcodeproj
Launching iPhone 6s (iOS 12.1)...
Building using "xcodebuild -project HelloWorld.xcodeproj -configuration Debug -scheme HelloWorld -destination id=32CE8569-3EE3-4DDD-9963-E0ED0E8DA946 -derivedDataPath build"
User defaults from command line:

    IDEDerivedDataPathOverride = /Users/tokra/Documents/Code/bitbucket.fork/rn-test/HelloWorld/ios/build
```

I remember it built only once, since then I cannot force rebuild.

Is there any way how to force build xcode in cli using react-native?

Comment: Have you tried running the app from Xcode rather than using `react-native run-ios`?

Comment: i do, its working form there, but i would expect react-native tool to work correctly :-( without need of opening another tool